# How to get the current language in a Sitecore Powershell editor (context menu) script?

Tags: powershell-extensions

How can I find which language the editor is currently working in when running a script from the context menu?

```
Get-Item .
```

Returns the item, but in the context language that the script session is in.

Comment: you can use the -Language parameter in the Get-Item call.

`Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/xxx" -Language "en"`

Comment: I need to know what language the item is in as the editor is working on it, not get it in a specific language.

Comment: How about this? `$SitecoreContextItem.Language.Name # Returns the language name`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWest - does exactly what I needed. Please add as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several variables found in the [book](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/interfaces/variables) which should make your life easier authoring scripts.

The following variable will give you the language for the script item.

```powershell
$SitecoreContextItem.Language.Name # Returns the language name
```

Comment: Ah, hidden away in the "Interfaces" chapter - I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

You can see by the dropdown "Current Language" under Home - UI Context in Powershell ISE:
[image]

You can also change if you have multiple languages on your instance

Comment: I need to get that value in a Sitecore Powershell script that the editor runs from a context menu. They aren't working in the ISE

Comment: In the case I showed you can directly get the context language using the Sitecore API.
For example: 
$language = [Sitecore.Context]::Language
the $language variable will store the context language which is english in this case

Comment: Yes, but this is the context language of the script session, not the editor's item view - right?

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: Which, unfortunately, isn't what I need. An editor is going to right click on an item and choose a script from the context menu. In that script I want to know which language the item is currently being viewed in.

Comment: If I understand correctly it will use the language of the item being selected. If you are using content editor and the item is on language English it will use that language as the context language. If you change the language you should see it reflected on the script execution